# Kaltura API C# How to get Value of StringEnum

Tags: c#, enums

Attempting to retrieve the Value of an EntryStatus(class further down), ie ("READY", "DELETED", "ERROR_IMPORTING") in a manner similar to the immediately below

```
EntryStatus test = EntryStatus.DELETED;
Console.WriteLine(test);
EntryStatus value = test;
string val = value.ToString();//see note1
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

The result of the above code is:

```
3
3
```

I would like to have the second Console.WriteLine to return "DELETED"
I do not understand how to retrieve the alphabetic part of the enum.

note1: changing this line to
`int val = (int)value;`
gives an error of Cannot Convert EntryStatus to int. This enum seems not to behave like other C# enums.

The EntryStatus is child class of StringEnum.

Edit: EntryStatus is part of the Kaltura Generated API and should not be modified.

```cs
public sealed class EntryStatus : StringEnum
{
    public static readonly EntryStatus ERROR_IMPORTING = new EntryStatus("-2");
    public static readonly EntryStatus ERROR_CONVERTING = new EntryStatus("-1");
    public static readonly EntryStatus IMPORT = new EntryStatus("0");
    public static readonly EntryStatus INFECTED = new EntryStatus("virusScan.Infected");
    public static readonly EntryStatus SCAN_FAILURE = new EntryStatus("virusScan.ScanFailure");
    public static readonly EntryStatus PRECONVERT = new EntryStatus("1");
    public static readonly EntryStatus READY = new EntryStatus("2");
    public static readonly EntryStatus DELETED = new EntryStatus("3");
    public static readonly EntryStatus PENDING = new EntryStatus("4");
    public static readonly EntryStatus MODERATE = new EntryStatus("5");
    public static readonly EntryStatus BLOCKED = new EntryStatus("6");
    public static readonly EntryStatus NO_CONTENT = new EntryStatus("7");

    private EntryStatus(string name) : base(name) { }
}
```

The base class `StringEnum` is:

Edit: The StringEnum class is part of the Kaltura Generated API, should not change

```
public class StringEnum
{
  private readonly string name;

  protected StringEnum(string name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public static StringEnum Parse(Type type, string name)
  {
    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
      object val = field.GetValue(null);
      if (val.GetType().BaseType == typeof(StringEnum))
      {
        if (val.ToString() == name)
          return (StringEnum)val;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Please accept System.Reflection, EntryStatus class and StringEnum class as givens for the problem. Modifications to EntryStatus and StringEnum can be done with the keyword partial only. I am attempting to understand the Kaltura Generated API library these are part of. All of your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your block of code right after the paragraph starting _"I call the API,"_ has no relation to your question that I can see.  There's no `EntryStatus` or `StringEnum` in there.  Please replace that with something that someone can use to repro what you are talking about.  I got halfway through and said "huh?"

Comment: After having gone through this, why not just use a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: @Flydog57 The StringEnum and EntryStatus classes are part of the Kaltura API's generated code.  I would prefer not to edit them. My code is attempting to interface with the generated code. I will edit the block of code after the paragraph starting "I call the API" to be more clear as per your suggestion later today. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Don't forget that if you have an autogenerated class that you include in your project, you can make some level of changes to that class by using the `partial` keyword (without changing the auto-generated code).  You can't get rid of artifacts, and you can't change something from `private` to `public` in a `partial class` file, but you can add stuff to the class.

Comment: Do you always get a `2`, or do you only get it from an entry like `public static readonly EntryStatus READY = new EntryStatus("2");`?  What do you want to get?  What would you like to get from an entry like `public static readonly EntryStatus INFECTED = new EntryStatus("virusScan.Infected");`?

Comment: I updated my answer.  I still find this a big of a weird situation.

Comment: @Flydog57 it is a bit odd of a situation, I agree. I do not understand why Kaltura chose to make a stringenum instead of an integer enum. I have to roll with it though. In my revised post, do you believe that including the base class for EntryStatus was not needed? I will be posting more Kaltura API questions, I want to make them better than this question was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-- Update --**

This is an update after the re-write of your question.

I'm not quite sure what to call what to call what you are looking for.  Right now, I used "OtherName".

This solution assumes two things.

1. The *Kaltura Generated API* (that should not be modified) exists as source in your project
2. Names associated with your `EntryStatus` things are unique (or mostly unique).

Possible Solution:

Create a new file in your project named *EntryStatus.partial.cs*.  Add the following code:

```
public sealed partial class EntryStatus
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _namesDictionary = null;

    public string AsOtherName()
    {
        if (_namesDictionary == null)
        {
            var fields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
            _namesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(fields.Length);
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                var fieldValue = field.GetValue(null);
                var fieldName = (fieldValue as EntryStatus).ToString();
                _namesDictionary[fieldName] = field.Name;
            }
        }

        return _namesDictionary[ToString()];
    }
}
```

That acts to modify the `EntryStatus` definition, but without touching the existing code.  If that's too intimate a relationship, you'd need to build a class that reflects over the EntryStatus class and builds that dictionary.

When it's all finished, `EntryStatus.ERROR_CONVERTING.AsOtherName()` returns  `"ERROR_CONVERTING"`.

Then again, what's the point of typing `EntryStatus.ERROR_CONVERTING` and having a whole lot of code only to come up with `"ERROR_CONVERTING"`

**--- Old Answer ---**

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but this might help:

First, I changed your `Parse` function to be generic, and to include a `TryParse` method as well (trust me, you'll appreciate it).  Your current `Parse` returns `null` on failure.  The expectation of most users is that an exception is thrown will be thrown from a `Parse` method on failure.

The code below does what I think you are describing, but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't do what you want.  See my suggested changes below for what I think you want.

The biggest change is that I changed your `FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();` to `var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static);`  Your `EntryStatus` class only has static members, and it's not instantiable by anyone outside itself (so it doesn't really matter).

The new `Parse` (and `TryParse`) code:

```
public static bool TryParse<T>(string name, out StringEnum stringEnum) where T : StringEnum
{
    stringEnum = null;
    var type = typeof(T);
    var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        var val = field.GetValue(null);
        if (val is StringEnum typedVal)
        {
            if (typedVal.ToString() == name)
            {
                stringEnum = typedVal;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and

```
public static StringEnum Parse<T>(string name) where T: StringEnum
{
    if (StringEnum.TryParse<T>(name, out var val))
    {
        return val;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;        //you should probably make this throw
    }
}
```

With that, if I say this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(StringEnum.Parse<EntryStatus>("virusScan.Infected"));
```

I get

```
virusScan.Infected
```

**So...**

What I think you want instead is to change:

```
if (typedVal.ToString() == name)    //in my TryParse method
```

to

```
if (field.Name == name)
```

Now, if you run `StringEnum.Parse<EntryStatus>("SCAN_FAILURE")` you will get:

```
virusScan.ScanFailure
```

Is that close to what you are talking about?  If you want a better answer, you will need to remove most of what starts with the paragraph that starts with *"I call the API"* and replace it with text and code that makes up a [Minimal Reproduceable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  For example the code block immediately after the *"I call the API"* paragraph does not include `StringEnum` or `EntryStatus`.  I really can't tell what you are talking about.

As a final note, you may want to include an *implicit operator* on your `StringEnum` class that allows implicit conversions to string.  If you don't want implicit conversions, you should at least provide an *explicit operator* to allow *casting* to strings.  See: [User-defined Implicit and Explicit Conversion Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate the comments on how to get a better answer. I was not clear in what I was asking from the answers here. I do need more practice writing concise questions. Most of the code is from the Kaltura Generated API that don't want to change. Please see the edits to the post in an attempt to clarify my question.

Comment: The post has been completely rewritten, as I had multiple posters say they could not determine what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to model the [KalturaEntryStatus](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/General_Objects/Enums/KalturaEntryStatus) and other similar enums. In my opinion is reflection a bit overkill here. So I propose another solution, which is based on a simple `Dictionary<string, string>` as also suggested by @Flydog57.
The sample contains only two enums with only 2 members:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains the various return codes of Kaltura API functions.
/// </summary>
public class KalturaEnum
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the return codes for function XXX.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly KalturaEnum KalturaEntryStatus = new KalturaEnum(nameof(KalturaEntryStatus),
        ("-2", "Error importing"),
        ("-1", "Error converting")
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the return codes for function YYY.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly KalturaEnum KalturaBatchJobType = new KalturaEnum(nameof(KalturaBatchJobType),
        ("ReachInternal.ReachInternalQueueHandler", "Reach internal queue handler"),
        ("0", "Convert")
        );

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> values;

    private KalturaEnum(string enumName, params (string Code, string Description)[] values)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enumName))
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(enumName)}' cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(enumName));
        EnumName = enumName;
        this.values = values.ToDictionary(a => a.Code, a => a.Description, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of this enumeration (not really usefull...).
    /// </summary>
    public string EnumName { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the description of a return code by using a case-insensitive search.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">The return code of a API function.</param>
    /// <returns>The description for <paramref name="code"/> or "Unknown return value '<paramref name="code"/>' for the type <see cref="EnumName"/>."</returns>
    public string GetDescription(string code) => code != null && values.TryGetValue(code, out var name) ? name : $"Unknown return value '{code ?? "null"}' for the type {EnumName}.";
}
```

Test and output:

```
Console.WriteLine(KalturaEnum.KalturaEntryStatus.GetDescription("-2"));
Console.WriteLine(KalturaEnum.KalturaBatchJobType.GetDescription("1"));
```

```
Error importing  
Unknown return value '1' for the type KalturaBatchJobType.
```

In your code it would look like this:

```
foreach (MediaEntry MediaEntry in result.Objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(KalturaEnum.KalturaEntryStatus.GetDescription(MediaEntry.Status)); 
}
```

Comment: I have heavily edited the question, as the original question was as clear as mud. Thank you for your time and original answer.